# How to overwrite/update the file that is selected / PHP

Tags: php

I would like to ask if how to overwrite/update the file that is selected. I have a table wherein it has a file named File1. and I wanna edit that selected row and change the File1 to File2 WITHOUT adding the FILE2 in the directory of the folder, I wanna remove File1 from the Directory Folder and be replaced by the File2.

Here's my code for the MySQL and moveuploadfile.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    include 'connection.php';

    $storedFile="../files/RepositoryFiles/".basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $research_photo="../files/Images/".basename($_FILES["research_photo"]["name"]);

    if(file_exists($storedFile) or file_exists($research_photo)){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Research File is already Existing!'); location.href='../admin/AddResearch.php?adding=failed';</script>";
    }
    else if($_FILES["file"]["size"] && $_FILES["research_photo"]["size"] > 10000000){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Research File should be less than 10MB!'); location.href='../admin/AddResearch.php?adding=failed';</script>";
    }
    else {
    $researchId = $_POST['idResearch'];
    $research_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['research_title']);
    $research_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['research_type']);
    $research_timeline = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['research_timeline']);
    // $storedFile="../files/RepositoryFiles/".basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $storedFile);
    $research_description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['research_description']);
    $research_author = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['research_author']);
    // $research_photo="../files/Images/".basename($_FILES["research_photo"]["name"]);
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["research_photo"]["tmp_name"], $research_photo);
            $sql = "UPDATE tbl_repository SET research_title = ?, research_type = ?, research_timeline  = ?,
            research_file = ?, research_description = ?, research_author = ?, research_photo = ? WHERE ID = ? ";    
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)){
        echo "SQL Error" . mysqli_error($stmt);
    }
    else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sssssssi", $research_title, $research_type, $research_timeline, $storedFile, $research_description, $research_author,$research_photo,$researchId); 
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfuly Updated!'); location.href='../admin/ViewResearch.php?updating=success';</script>";
    }
}
}

?>
```

I tried the unlink but it didn't work for me, I tried uhm storing the values of research file and research photo in two variables wherein the first one stores the current file/photo and remove it and the second one is the new file that the user selected and upload in both database and move in the file directory.

Idk if I make sense but I tried my best explaining what I am currently struggling. Thank you!

edit:
here's the image for reference:
as you can see it is stored in file/images and file/RepositoryFiles
This is what I am fetching.
[image]

so here, I have selected the new file and photo.
[image]

so here's the result after I update the selected row.
[image]

I wanna remove the previous file/photo after I updated with new Image/file.

Comment: I'm a bit lost. Are you looking to replace an image? Side note: no need to do manual escaping when you're doing prepared statements. You can delete all the `mysqli_real_escape_string` calls.

Comment: your problem is not clear, if you have issue with unlink() , may be address that is given is not correct

Comment: @El_Vanja yes, I need a replacement for both image and files. My update is working and it is updating on mysql, but the thing is instead of overwriting the file, it adds another file.
so basically if my current file is File1, and if I update that file to file2, it'll replace it but in folder the file1 is still there, i need to remove file1 as soon as i updated it with file2.

Comment: Would it make sense for you that the files use the same name instead of different ones?

Comment: @El_Vanja I have updated the post, sorry if I confused you.

Comment: @mehriabbasi I have updated the post, sorry if I confused you.

Comment: Your code doesn't show the `unlink` attempts. Can you include that in your question?

Comment: Do not use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Answer (score 0):

you can simply delete files by `unlink()` method.

Just, This is important to gave it correct path.

for example `unlink("/var/www/test/file.png");`.

As I'm checking your code, there is no usage of `unlink()` method or maybe you have another issue.